# Oracle: copy row while updating one field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

Please note: I *am* asking the question I want answered.  I know this question means the database is set up poorly.  So I will vote down any answers that suggest changing the way the table is set up.

I need to duplicate a bunch of rows, while changing one value.

```
name   col1 col2
dave   a    nil
sue    b    nil
sam    c    5
```

needs to become:

```
name   col1 col2
dave   a    nil
dave   a    a
sue    b    nil
sue    b    a
same   c    5
```

IE for all entries in this table where `col2 is null`, create a new entry in the table where `name` and `col1` are the copied, and `col2` is `a`.

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` when you occasionally state `nil` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (name, col1, col2)
SELECT t.name, t.col1, 'a'
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.col2 IS NULL
```

That's assuming neither the `name` or `col1` columns are a primary key or have a unique constraint on either.

Comment: Previous comment deleted: I found my bug.  Yep, this worked.  Thanks!

Comment: This code requires repeating the list of table columns, and will break if a column is added to the table.  Is there a way to do it without listing the uninteresting columns?

Answer (score 3):

Will this do it?

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
       (SELECT name, col1, 'a'
          FROM yourtable 
         WHERE col2 is NULL);
```

Comment: +1 good answer, although it doesn't actually work in my case.  I'm only populating some of the fields in the table.

Comment: Should, but risks an ORA error if there's more columns in the table.

Comment: Yup, the assumption was the table had the columns in the example.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of columns is large, you could copy the data you want into a temporary table, alter the data in the temporary table as you wanted, then copy the contents of the temporary table back into the original, and delete the temporary table.